# SNS Topic- SQS Subscriptions with CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-cdk

I have created a SNS Topic and subscribed a SQS Queue with to this Topic using CDK.
I would like to understand does SQS Queue automatically polls messages published through this SNS Topic?

Answer (score 0):

SNS automatically "pushes" messages to subscribed SQS queues:

> [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sqs-as-subscriber.html): Amazon SNS allows applications to send time-critical messages to multiple subscribers through a “push” mechanism, eliminating the need to periodically check or “poll” for updates.

The integration works this way whether created with the CDK or not.